# Get posts with multiple categories

Tags: posts, wp-query

How to get just the common posts of 2 different categories? consider this category tree:

```
posttype
-news
-arrangement
--course
--competetion
--other
region
-region1
-region2
-region3
```

Now I want to get the posts in categories 'news' and 'region2'. I have tried this:

```
$query = new WP_Query('category__and=12,32'); // 12=news, 32=region2
```

But then I get all the posts which have either category 12 or category 32. I want those posts which have both 12 and 32.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`category__and`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters) needs to be an array of category ID's

> **category__and** (array) - use category id.

You can modify your code to look like this

```
$query = new WP_Query( array('category__and' => array(12,32)));
```